# How to convert html blade that contains dynamic data from database to PDF in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to write code that converts html blade to PDF using tcpdf in laravel.

This is the controller code which i use to convert:

```
public function htmlToPDF()
{  
    $view=view('PdfDemo');
    $html_content =$view->render();
    PDF::SetTitle('Sample PDF');
    PDF::AddPage();
    PDF::writeHTML($html_content, true, false, true, false, '');
    PDF::Output('SamplePDF.pdf');
}
```

When I put static data on my view(PdfDemo) everything runs successfully, but the problem is when I put dynamic data with some variables in the blade as the following:

```
                        <table>
                          <?php $i=0?>
                            @if(count($names))
                                @foreach($names as $n)
                                    <tr><td>
                                    <label>Name{{$i}}:</label>{{$n}}</td>
                                    <tr><td><hr></td></tr>
                                    <?php $index = $index+1; ?>
                                @endforeach
                            @endif
                        </table>
```

Here $names is the result of select statement in other function of controller, then I pass it to the blade like this:

```
 return view('PdfDemo',compact('names'));
```

In this case the blade appear exactly as I want, but when I try to convert to PDF it shows error, $name not defined.

Comment: Not related to the question, but use the `$index` at foreach, that way you dont need to call php at the blade.

Comment: You are right, i will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
$view = View::make('PdfDemo',compact('names'));
$contents = (string) $view;
// or
$contents = $view->render();
```

When you use `View::make()` it gets the HTML code of blade file as HTML content after adding dynamic variable's values.

Comment: This is what i want  but it does not work, i try it but nothing change

Comment: At first when i try problem still found, but i put the select statement which gives names in the convert function and do as you write, then no errors appears, but it still process the shows this error : Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Comment: That is a totally different problem. You should increase max execution time either in `php.ini` file or `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: Finally it solved without change execution time ^_^ ,the time problem was in my code because i there is some unnecessary bootstrap divs and when i removed it the code runs successfully, Thanks a lot ^^

Comment: It work on both cases, if i put or remove make, but can you give me when should i use make?

Comment: When you want to get blade content not as view but html content.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the data to the view in the `htmlToPDF` function.

try to change it to:

```
public function htmlToPDF($names)
{  
    $view=view('PdfDemo', compact('names');
    $html_content =$view->render();
    PDF::SetTitle('Sample PDF');
    PDF::AddPage();
    PDF::writeHTML($html_content, true, false, true, false, '');
    PDF::Output('SamplePDF.pdf');
}
```

Comment: Nothing change :(

Comment: I also try to put the same select statement on this function then compact names as you write, it still process until give this : Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Comment: can you add the part in your controller return the response.

Comment: It works successfully now ^_^ , i add the select statement to the function and compact names without add it as parameter of the function, and about execution time problem i remove some additional tags as unecessary bootstrap divs then everything becomes ok, thank you :))))

Comment: Need to add a closing bracesses here $view=view('PdfDemo', compact('names');